# Can the ID from a referenced column be obtained when using SharePoint's Data View Part?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, dataviewwebpart

I have a Data View Part pulling from a list that has a lookup column to another list (title linked by ID)

And somewhere in the XSLT of the data view web part configuration, it reads

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ColumnX"/>
```

Now since ColumnX is a reference to another list (linked to item), how do I go about obtaining the ID rather than the text? Is there a ddwrt trick out there?

Answer (score 0):

The value of a Lookup Field is in the format of "ID;#Text". To get the ID value, we use is regular xslt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@ColumnX, ';#')" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, but that won't since @ColumnX only has the "title" even though is linked to another list. I was hoping to see if there was a way to obtain the title and the ID which one can then apply substring-before.

Comment: So when you use <xsl:value-of select="@ColumnX"/>, you only get the title, no ID and no ';#'? Something is wrong. What is the type of ColumnX? Is it a Lookup field or just a Text field?

Comment: ColumnX is of type look up. It seems the DVWP filters the ID for you.